# bash shell script case statement for two variables

Tags: bash, shell, case

I want to create a case statement including two expressions, my imagination is to look like this :

```
a=true
b=false 

case [ "$a" || "$b"]  in  #<-- how can I do this with a case statement ?

true)echo "a & b are true" ;;
false)echo "a or b are not true" ;;

esac
```

Is it possible to do it with case instead of if ?

Thanks

Comment: A case statement doesn't "include" variables, see `help case`. It is `case word in ...`, which means you could write `case "foo" in "foo") echo "foo found" ;; esac`.

Comment: ok , I mean expressions - the syntaxis is case statement in , is there a way to use two expressions in one case statement ? Example : 'case expression1 & expression2 in' or 'case expression1 or expression2 in' ?

Comment: This might help http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html

Comment: @Inian : Thanks , but this describes a situation with only one expression : 
`case "$1" in `, the variable $1 is the expression in that case is there to add more expressions to this single case statement ? case EXPRESSION in CASE1) COMMAND-LIST;; CASE2) COMMAND-LIST;; ... CASEN) COMMAND-LIST;; esac

Comment: I think you are mixing concepts -- Two expressions joined by `OR`, `AND`, ... etc form actually a logical expression. Thus, its output cannot be `something` apart from either `Logical true` or `Logical false`. Logical operations (|| &&) can be used inside `$((···))`

Comment: @Jdamian : I think I'm not making it clear , that is why I'm going to show you as a simple code : `a=true        b=false     #I want to use a case statement not if - will this be possible ?       case [[$a or $b]] in  #<-- this is the part I;m not sure how to write     true) echo "both variables are true;;   false) echo "one fo the variables is not true" ;; esac`     Can I write this with a case statement or it is impossible without using if ?

Comment: In `case WORD in `, **`WORD`** must be a character string. Therefore the problem is how to turn a logical operation result into a string. As I said, the `bash` arithmetic `$((···))` returns a string, unlike `[···]` and `[[···]]` do, but their logical outcomes can be checked using `$?`.

Comment: Store the result of a `$a or $b` in a variable and then use a case statement on that variable.

Comment: @Jdamian `$((...))` supports `&&` and `||`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example but it's about strings, not real logical expressions:

```
$ cat > foo.sh
a=true
b=false
case $a$b in        # "catenate" a and b, two strings
    *false*)        # if there is substring false (ie. truefalse, falsetrue or falsefalse) in there
        echo false  # it's false
        ;;
    *)
        echo true   # otherwise it must be true
        ;;
esac

$ bash foo.sh
false
```

Answer (score 2):

`bash` doesn't have Boolean constants; `true` and `false` are just strings, with no direct way to treat them as Boolean values. If you use the standard encoding of 0 and 1 as Boolean values, you can use `$((...))`:

```
a=1  # true
b=0  # false
case $(( a && b )) in
  1) echo 'a && b == true' ;;
  0) echo 'a && b == false' ;;
esac
```